# Creating personal extension and host over local network

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, raspberry-pi4, crx

I'm working on an extension that I want to use at 3 locations on probably 100 computers. Rather then re-imaging the computers every time I have have to update the extension, Can I host the extension on a pi at each sight and set a policy with the update url pointed at my extension?

If so how would I go about hosting my own extension?

Comment: As I understand from your question and tags, you are developing a Chrome Extension and would like to update it automatically. Unfortunately, there is no way of doing this automatically for security reasons.

Comment: @IvanD Interesting when you reopen chrome does it auto reload the extension?

Comment: Definitely not if it is installed locally, but if you publish it to the Chrome Extension store, then maybe

Comment: @IvanD I just tested it and I think it does if I change the code in the local directory. only if I change the code in the actually directory I just wonder if I package it then overwrite the directory and reopen chrome if that would be enough to make it update automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure, you need to actually test it